# Update the number of likes in Post (Firebase)

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

```
var postRef:DatabaseReference {
    return Database.database().reference().child("posts")
}

@IBAction func LikePostTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

postRef.observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with: { [self] (snapshot) in
    
        if snapshot.children.allObjects is [DataSnapshot] {
            
            count =  count + 1
            LikeCount.text = "\(count)"
            LikeCount.textColor = UIColor.red
            postRef.updateChildValues(["likes":count])
    }
    })
    
    
}
```

I am trying to update the number of likes for each post in my database. However when i click the like button its saves the number of likes in a new child node in firebase and not in the likes child node on the particular post. Here is a picture that shows what i mean.

PICTURE LINK: https://i.stack.imgur.com/64wLn.png

Comment: If it is creating a new entry each time then you need to five id of that post or of that like counter associated to that post then update it on basis of that id

Comment: the post IDs are randomly generated using the ChildbyAutoId, how would i be able to call to the specific id depending on the post that is liked?

Comment: Fetch it by key not by value
example in php
"some_key_name"="xyz value"
to get it 
$_POST['some_key_name']

Comment: could you provide an example in swift code please? I am still a beginner and i don't really know about php.

Comment: I found this example of updating saved data from: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-update

DatabaseReference hopperRef = usersRef.child("gracehop");
Map<String, Object> hopperUpdates = new HashMap<>();
hopperUpdates.put("nickname", "Amazing Grace");

hopperRef.updateChildrenAsync(hopperUpdates);